# Does Superman have a higher IQ on Earth than he would have on Krypton?

Tags: dc, superman

Does our sun enhance Superman's mind in the same way it enhances his body?

Is his IQ higher on Earth than it would be on Krypton?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the relevant [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powers_and_abilities_of_Superman#Superhuman_Intelligence), itself referencing [The Amazing World of Superman, 1973](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/amazing-world-of-superman-1-official-metropolis-ed/4000-244120/) (which I sadly don't have access to), the answer is a resounding Yes (even though it doesn't mention his actual numeric IQ value).

> Superman is often shown to have a flawless, eidetic memory of everything he has ever seen, read, heard, or otherwise experienced. In most portrayals, Superman is capable of multilingualism and is able to learn, speak and understand any language he comes in contact with. Superman possesses intellect that surpasses genius-level. People from Krypton already had genius-level intellect, being a society thousands of years ahead of Earth in technology. In the presence of a yellow sun, Superman's intelligence is further enhanced, literally to super-humanoid levels, giving him super intelligence and allowing his brain to operate faster than a supercomputer.

Comment: His brain would have to work pretty fast in order for him to navigate when he's using his super speed. Moving that fast requires good reaction times.

Comment: Given his vastly increased physical abilities which as others have pointed out require at least a vastly FASTER mind it seems to me that if supe is more intelligent than humans than he would be many times more intelligent although his intelligence is not really emphasized IIRC.