# Is Superman smart?

Tags: dc, superman

So I tried searching this on Google but I found the  [answer](https://www.dc.com/blog/2021/11/11/ask-the-question-how-smart-is-superman) inconclusive.

Anyways here by smart I simply mean smarter than the average human, like I have never seen Superman display a feat of his "super intelligence", maybe because he relies on brute strength in most of his comics. I mean Clark Kent is clumsy and goofy and its supposed to be 'part of the disguise' but is it?

I know he is not dumb, but is he smarter than the average human?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Superman have a higher IQ on Earth than he would have on Krypton?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/127325/31394)

Comment: Superman is *supposed to be* way smarter than writers who make stories about him, but it doesn't seem they even try to emulate that. That would mean he would be much more than a "superhero". Check Watchmen for that.

Comment: [Although...](https://twitter.com/jamesgrime/status/565233416082587648?t=9VcIMDMDCHSRA6WgUTLMWw&s=19)

Comment: In the answer to [your last question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/274601/what-is-the-context-of-this-superman-comic-panel-in-which-luthor-is-saying-yes/274603), Luthor admitted Superman was quite resourceful indeed.

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted. I have wondered this ever since the Batman and Spawn crossover when Batman comments Spawn is 'as thick as Clark'.

Comment: @Clockwork, funnily enough this question arose in my mind after i read your comment about superman being the smartest on that question

Comment: Does the silverage count ? Because there are stories from then when Superman builds extremely advanced machinery from scratch or read and remember every library on an entire planet in seconds.

Comment: @BjornEriksson The phrasing of the question makes me think _any_ continuity would count.

Comment: Superman fans are known to have remarked in the once-upon-a-time that a panel was always missing in "World's Finest": "Off to Gotham City, but first, I'd better take a stupid pill!"

Comment: @Blaze You remind me that during a quick search, I noticed people mentioned Superman was often a victim of "plot-induced stupidity"

Answer (score 7):

After all these decades of comics, movies, TV, cartoons, and whatnot, Superman has been as smart as the writer of the moment required. This may be in contradiction of StackExchange protocols, but I'm presenting overall generalities of the mythos rather than specifics.

- Kal-El is the son of one of Krypton's most brilliant scientists (and his mom was no dummy). Unless genetics really fumbled, it seems likely Superman is *well* above average intelligence. (Many "Elseworld" scenarios that have Kal-El not becoming Superman often depict him as becoming a scientist)
- Clark Kent is always a mild-mannered alter-ego for Superman, but Clark is usually depicted as an award-winning investigative journalist. That isn't a job for low-watt bulbs. (Some stories even have Batman acknowledging that Superman might not be a master detective, but his reporter skills are pretty sharp at finding a clue trail.)
- There are countless times where Superman uses his X-Ray Vision to assess car engines, computer circuit boards, time bombs, human anatomy, or even mad scientist machines. He does so and immediately identifies any problem and course of action. On occasion, with Microscopic Vision and/or Heat Vision, he then remedies problem on the spot. That is a compendium of knowledge and skills to equal the entire graduating classes of a university and a technical college.
- Whenever the incarnation of Superman allows the power to fly in deep space, he does all the interstellar navigation in his head.  Most impressive. (on that note, I'll end with a scene from *DC Comics Presents* #29 (1981)):
  [image]

Comment: I think this answer is a better answer on how smart Superman is generally represented; especially the fact he uses his X-ray vision to analyse about _anything_ (which goes to show his vast knowledge at least).

Comment: Brings up a good point...is he inherently intelligent, or did the cultural/scientific achievements and advanced educational technology of Krypton force-fill his mind with a ridiculous amount of knowledge on the ride over, negating the need for him to learn it in more Earth-typical ways?

Answer (score 4):

He is depicted as being quite smart/resourceful in [*Superman: The Animated Series (1996)*](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_The_Animated_Series) in at least four occurrences:

- In the episode [Mxyzpixilated](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Mxyzpixilated), Mxyzptlk from the fifth dimension came to challenge him, and the only way to send him back was to make him pronounce his name backward, which sent the imp back to his dimension for three months. Throughout the episode, he was able to trick the imp several times with quite some ease.

- In the episode [The Late Mr. Kent](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/The_Late_Mr._Kent), we also get to see Superman doing some detective job as Clark Kent. An innocent man had being framed for murder and thief, and Clark was the only one who believed him to be innocent. In the end, he managed to prove the man truly was innocent, without having to use any of his superpower (although that ended up with someone trying to murder him).
- On a lesser note, in the episode [Double Dose](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Double_Dose), Livewire and Parasite teamed up to take him on. After having absorbed Superman's power, Parasite decided to betray Livewire by absorbing her power for himself too. Not only was he took weak to fight back, he was facing someone who had his own super power along with the ability to electrocute him to death. When he desperately tried to keep his distance with a broomstick and Parasite taunted him by zapping it to set it on fire, he did not take long to figure out he could use that same fire to set off the office's fire sprinkler, which could short circuit Livewire's power (which Parasite had absorbed). [Here's an excerpt](https://youtu.be/-TcTyHoP6n8?t=237) of that episode (embedded video disabled).
- One notable example is in part two of the episode [The Main Man](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/The_Main_Man). Superman and [Lobo](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Lobo) had both been captured by a villain called the [Preserver](https://Preserver), because they were both the last survivor of their respective species. They were kept in some kind of cage that kept them weakened (red sun for Superman and gas for Lobo), along with many other species which are also the last of their kind, all living in cages that reproduce their respective natural inhabitat. When they both managed to escape, they were still getting chased by a gang that were after Lobo. Superman quickly looked around and noticed a cage containing some kind of animal that could help, but got interrupted when he was in the process of opening it by the gang attacking him. At first, they believed he was about to release a fierce beast to come and devour them, so they threw him in. It turns out the cage contained a [dodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodo), which is an extinct bird from Earth. Hence, the room also had an artificial yellow sun, allowing him to absorb it and regain his full power.